# If condition does not follow (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

Creating a SharePoint Portal using JavaScript and HTML where the problem is when i'm inputting a number around 100,000 to 800,000; ex(523,546) it would enter in the first if condition and do the statement below in the. even though the value is less than the given MDV "Total Estimated Freight".

The value of the pagetdv is inputted.

```
var pagetdvz = document.getElementById('pagetdv');
var pagesrz = document.getElementById('pagesr');
var pagemdvz = document.getElementById('pagemdv');
```

/*------------ Maximum Declared Value ----------*/

```
if (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 0)
document.getElementById('pagemdv').value = 1500000;

else if (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 1)
document.getElementById('pagemdv').value = 3000000;
```

/*------------ Dest + 20 Ftr  ----------*/

```
if ((document.getElementById('dropdest').selectedIndex == 0) && (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 0))
    document.getElementById('pagesr').value = 45900;

else if ((document.getElementById('dropdest').selectedIndex == 1) && (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 0))
    document.getElementById('pagesr').value = 50000;

else if ((document.getElementById('dropdest').selectedIndex == 2) && (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 0))
    document.getElementById('pagesr').value = 46700;

else if ((document.getElementById('dropdest').selectedIndex == 3) && (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 0))
    document.getElementById('pagesr').value = 47583.67;

else if ((document.getElementById('dropdest').selectedIndex == 4) && (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 0))
    document.getElementById('pagesr').value = 59981.33;

else if ((document.getElementById('dropdest').selectedIndex == 5) && (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 0))
    document.getElementById('pagesr').value = 45900;

else if ((document.getElementById('dropdest').selectedIndex == 6) && (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 0))
    document.getElementById('pagesr').value = 59000;

else if ((document.getElementById('dropdest').selectedIndex == 7) && (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 0))
    document.getElementById('pagesr').value = 45900;

else if ((document.getElementById('dropdest').selectedIndex == 8) && (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 0))
    document.getElementById('pagesr').value = 59,981.33;

else if ((document.getElementById('dropdest').selectedIndex == 9) && (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 0))
    document.getElementById('pagesr').value = 58500;

else if ((document.getElementById('dropdest').selectedIndex == 10) && (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 0))
    document.getElementById('pagesr').value = 49000;

else if ((document.getElementById('dropdest').selectedIndex == 11) && (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 0))
    document.getElementById('pagesr').value = 46700;

else if ((document.getElementById('dropdest').selectedIndex == 12) && (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 0))
    document.getElementById('pagesr').value = 51000;
```

/*------------ Dest + 40 Ftr----------*/

```
if ((document.getElementById('dropdest').selectedIndex == 0) && (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 1))
    document.getElementById('pagesr').value = 89600;

else if ((document.getElementById('dropdest').selectedIndex == 1) && (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 1))
    document.getElementById('pagesr').value = 95500;

else if ((document.getElementById('dropdest').selectedIndex == 2) && (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 1))
    document.getElementById('pagesr').value = 91096.87;

else if ((document.getElementById('dropdest').selectedIndex == 3) && (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 1))
    document.getElementById('pagesr').value = 94944.66;

else if ((document.getElementById('dropdest').selectedIndex == 4) && (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 1))
    document.getElementById('pagesr').value = 119739.26;

else if ((document.getElementById('dropdest').selectedIndex == 5) && (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 1))
    document.getElementById('pagesr').value = 89600;

else if ((document.getElementById('dropdest').selectedIndex == 6) && (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 1))
    document.getElementById('pagesr').value = 117487.73;

else if ((document.getElementById('dropdest').selectedIndex == 7) && (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 1))
    document.getElementById('pagesr').value = 89600;

else if ((document.getElementById('dropdest').selectedIndex == 8) && (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 1))
    document.getElementById('pagesr').value = 119739.26;

else if ((document.getElementById('dropdest').selectedIndex == 9) && (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 1))
    document.getElementById('pagesr').value = 113000;

else if ((document.getElementById('dropdest').selectedIndex == 10) && (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 1))
    document.getElementById('pagesr').value = "--Null--";

else if ((document.getElementById('dropdest').selectedIndex == 11) && (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 1))
    document.getElementById('pagesr').value = 91096.87;

else if ((document.getElementById('dropdest').selectedIndex == 12) && (document.getElementById('dropct').selectedIndex == 1))
    document.getElementById('pagesr').value = "--Null--";
```

/*------------ Total Estimated Freight ----------*/

```
if (document.getElementById('pagetdv').value > document.getElementById('pagemdv').value){
var tdva = parseFloat(pagetdvz.value) - parseFloat(pagemdvz.value);
var tdvb = tdva / 1000;
var tdvc = tdvb * 3.36;
var tef = tdvc + parseFloat(pagesrz.value);
  document.getElementById('pagetef').value = tef;
  } 
else if (document.getElementById('pagetdv').value <= document.getElementById('pagemdv').value)
document.getElementById('pagetef').value = document.getElementById('pagesr').value;
```

Comment: FYI: store the result of getElementById and use that instead of calling it every time you need the element. Will improve readability,maintenance, and reduce typing

Comment: Holy-scrollwheel, Batman :) Is there a way to simplify this to demonstrate the problem you're having or error you're running into?